# Page Title is missing on Pages with add_submenu_page

Tags: wordpress

Adding sub menus is easy with [`add_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) and is working fine as long if you define a `$parent_slug`:

```
add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
```

if you set the `$parent_slug` to `NULL` as described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page#Example) to hide it from any menu item the title of the page will get ignored (`$page_title`)

```
add_submenu_page( NULL, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
```

I've tested it with all versions from 3.3 up to the latest beta 4.0

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't explicitly call this out, but to include the page title you must use `'options.php'` as the `$parent_slug`.

```
add_submenu_page( 'options.php', $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
```

Comment: How did you figure this out? Does this have any unintended side-effects?

Comment: tripflex's comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/#comment-2470

`add_action('admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_submenu_page');
  
function wpdocs_register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 
        'options.php',
        'My Custom Submenu Page',
        'My Custom Submenu Page',
        'manage_options',
        'my-custom-submenu-page',
        'my_custom_submenu_page_callback',
    );
}`
> You would then access this page via this URL: /wp-admin/options.php?page=my-custom-submenu-page

Comment: As far as unintended side effects, I have not noticed any.

Answer (score 0):

Please try 'options.php' instead of NULL for $parent_slug argument.